# How to prevent the console title from being changed by another application

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PowerShell script which uses the `$host.ui.rawui.windowtitle` option to set the window title. My script then executes an interactive, character based application (let's call it myapp.exe). However, as long as myapp.exe is running, the window title is changed to the title of the myapp application. As soon as I exit myapp.exe, the title I originally set is shown again.
Is there any way to prevent the title from being changed by myapp.exe?
Thank you *very* much for any help in advance!

Kind regards,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can *prevent* other apps from changing the console window title. You may start a [thread job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_thread_jobs?view=powershell-7.2) using `Start-ThreadJob` that periodically resets the window title to your desired value if it has changed.

```sh
# Start a thread job to periodically reset the console window title
$null = Start-ThreadJob { param( $rawUI, $windowTitle )
    while( $true ) {
        # If the window title has changed, reset it
        if( $rawUI.WindowTitle -ne $windowTitle ) {
            $rawUI.WindowTitle = $windowTitle
        }
        # A delay is important so the CPU is not hogged
        Start-Sleep -Millis 250
    }
} -ArgumentList $host.ui.RawUI, 'My window title'

# For testing: Simulate another process that sets the window title:
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'foo bar'
```

You can see that "foo bar" briefly appears in the window title, but will be reset to our desired window title shortly after.

`Start-ThreadJob` requires PS 5.1 or newer. I've tried a solution for older PowerShell versions using `Start-Job`, but that doesn't work, propably because normal jobs run in a separate process, having no access to the PowerShell console that launched them.

`Start-ThreadJob` otoh runs in a thread in the same process, so it does have access to the console.

Comment: Hi!
That's a very interesting work-around, thanks!
Now, I'm not that familiar with that Start-ThreadJob function, so I hope you're willing to help me a bit. Looping is not necessary, because I only need to have the window renamed once, just after Myapp.exe start. So here's what I have:

$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "My Title"
& "c:\Program Files\Myapp\Myapp.exe"

How do I start the Start-ThreadJob just before Myapp.exe, wait one or two seconds and then let it issue the $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "My Title" command?
Thank you VERY much for your help in advance!

Kind regards,
Eric

Comment: @EricvanLoon You might insert a `Start-Sleep 2` to wait two seconds at the beginning of the thread job script and remove the `while` loop, but that could be unreliable if the system is loaded and MyApp.exe takes longer to start up.